# Getting data from another Foreign key - DRF

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

The relations of tables are shown in the picture below.
[image]

I have a main Table named `Product`. Two tables `ProductImage` and `OrderedProduct` have a Foreign key set to them.
I want to retrieve the image from `OrderedProduct`. How should I write the code for Serialization for it?
Thanks

This is my **model.py** file:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", null=True, blank=True)

class OrderedProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ordered_products')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class OrderedProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_name = serializers.CharField(source='product.name')
    product_price = serializers.FloatField(source='product.price')
    # product_img = >>> what should I do here? <<<

    class Meta:
        model = OrderedProduct
        fields = ('product', 'quantity',
                  'product_name', 'product_price', 'product_img')
```

I've read the documentation, and asked in some programming groups but couldn't find any good solution.
I am expecting someone to give a reference that leads to the solution.

Comment: Is there a reason behind separating the product and its image? if there is not just remove the ProductImage model and retrieve the image by using nested serializers or a to_representation function

Comment: I've separated product and image models, because there are multiple images for one product. Is there any way retrieving data from another foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can use the *SerializerMethodField* like that:

```
class OrderedProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_name = serializers.CharField(source='product.name')
    product_price = serializers.FloatField(source='product.price')
    product_imgs = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = OrderedProduct
        fields = ('product', 'quantity',
                  'product_name', 'product_price', 'product_imgs')

    def get_product_imgs(self, order):
        return list(order.product.product_images.all().values_list('image', flat=True))
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "product": 1,
        "quantity": 100,
        "product_name": "ProductX",
        "product_price": 123,
        "product_imgs": ["url1", "url2"]
    }
]
```

**Solution 2**

If you dont have a structure contraint i propose you to change this structure and create a serializer for each model and on order retrieve you send product object like that:

```
class ProductImagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = ('image',)


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_images = ProductImagesSerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'price', 'product_images')


class OrderedProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = OrderedProduct
        fields = ('product', 'quantity')
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "product": {
            "name": "productX",
            "price": 100,
            "product_images": [
                {
                    "image": "some_url"
                },
                {
                    "image": "some_url2"
                }
            ]
        },
        "quantity": 123
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    images = models.ManyToManyField(ProductImage) # you can select multiple images from here

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", null=True, blank=True)

class OrderedProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ordered_products')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

`serializers.py`

```py
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = ProductImage
       fields ["image"]

class OrderedProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_name = serializers.CharField(source='product.name')
    product_price = serializers.FloatField(source='product.price')
    product_img = serializer.ImageSerializer(source='product.image',many=true, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = OrderedProduct
        fields = ('product', 'quantity',
                  'product_name', 'product_price', 'product_img')
```

Comment: There are multiple images for one product. So, I separated the models and set a foreign key to the image model. And I did not notice the `OrderedProductSerializer` fields while minimizing the code for uploading it here. I've edited that.

Comment: Are you open to a completely new suggestion about your models?

Comment: Let me know if this works out for your case